# PhoneGap Build with own Plugins for just one platform

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

im currently doing some research concerning PhoneGap/Cordova and want to find out, whether it is possible to use the PhoneGap Build Web Service with a platform dependent plugin.

So imagine the following situation:

I want to use Bluetooth inside my application and Bluetooth is currently only available for Android, as I have seen in the list of plugins at GitHub. So I may include this Plugin using Eclipse + ADT. Now I want to use this for iOS too. So is it possible to upload this kind of platform specific app to PhoneGap build and create and iOS app out of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is right now not possible to build apps with custom plugins with phonegapbuild.